# Merge two tables with summing up values

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two tables,

`Table1`:

```
Key, Value
----------
1     10
2     20
3     30
```

`Table2`:

```
Key, Value
----------
3     30
4     40
5     50
```

How can merge them and get the following using SQL?

`Desired output`:

```
Key, Value
----------
1     10
2     20
3     60
4     40
5     50
```

In **Python** terminology, I guess it is called summing up two dictionaries.

PS: I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Did you try the UNION [ALL] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Union all` to combine two select queries and `sum` the `value` with `group by` key column

```
select key,sum(value) value
from 
(
select Key, Value from table1
union all
select Key, Value from table2
) a
group by key
```

or use `Full outer Join`

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Key, b.key),
       COALESCE(a.Value, 0) + COALESCE(b.value, 0)
FROM   table1 a
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 b
                    ON a.Key = b.Key
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient in terms of speed?

Comment: @celebisait You have to accept this answer if it solved your problems. And i guess the second one would more efficient. i don't know, but am i right @NoDisplayName?

Answer (score 2):

For more efficient in terms of speed, as much as possible avoid using `UNION/UNION ALL`. Try my answer below:

```
SELECT 
      NVL(A.Key,B.Key)[Key],
     (NVL(A.Value,0) + NVL(B.Value,0))[Value] 
FROM Table1 A
FULL JOIN Table2 B ON A.Key=B.Key
```

Comment: I am not sure which answer is more efficient in terms of speed.

Comment: As much as possible, just avoid the UNION/UNION ALL, With @NoDisplayName second query, it is the same as my answer only he uses COALESCE. And me, I used NVL. I think our answers are somewhat both efficient in terms of speed. It's up to you now what you're going to use. Thanks.

Comment: @Rigel1121 - intially you posted a wrong answer and after that you have edited. After the change its a replica of my answer. Avoid posting duplicate answers in future. No harsh feelings just a suggestion

Comment: @NoDisplayName, no I'm not posting duplicate a answer. Yes, I've posted a wrong answer a while back, but when I tried to double check my answer on my own using SQL Server 2012, I've realized that something is wrong in my query. So, I edited it. Then, by that time you also edited your answer. I've also research the counterpart  of ISNULL of SQL Server in Oracle which is NVL. So, don't be that rude, I'm just trying to help others with my best.

Comment: @Rigel1121 - I didn't say anything wrong or rude here. Its really good that you found that right answer but that answer is already suggested so i said not to post a duplicate answer. Again no harsh feelings. cheers+1

Comment: @NoDisplayName Ok sir, thanks. But, correction I don't copy your answer.    +1 too.

Comment: @Rigel1121 - You didn't copy my answer that I know dude. Duplicate is different from copying.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Ok sir, sorry for that. I just wanted to help on my own approach and style